# Buttons became small in android studio

Tags: android, xml, button, frontend

[buttons becomming small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVmlr.png)
when in run the app the buttons are becoming small....
please help me with the solution..
I have attached the image.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/roundtext"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.185"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.584" />
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the drawable `roundtext`. Maybe try experimenting with hardcoded values for `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the buttons is as expected - their width and height wrap the button's text completely.
The problem is probably with your custom background `@drawable/roundtext` which makes the buttons look a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving some `padding` to the button.

The padding is expressed in pixels for the left, top, right and bottom parts of the view. Padding can be used to offset the content of the view by a specific number of pixels. For instance, a left padding of 2 will push the view’s content by 2 pixels to the right of the left edge. **`The inner space of an element i.e.padding is space inside the element’s border`**.

So, either you can try adding

> android:padding="5dp"

where padding is added for all four sides ,or you can try adding `padding` specific to your required sides like below.

> android:paddingStart="5dp"
> android:paddingEnd="5dp"

So, your code may look like something as given below.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/roundtext"
    android:text="Login"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.185"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.584" />
```